# Magento 2: Layout doesnt update

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, layout

**After clearing the cache `default_head_blocks.xml` doesn't update.**

How I clear the cache

```
1. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

2. Flush Magento Cache in the admin
```

**What is the best way to clear magento 2 cache?**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: try php bin/magento cache:flush or php bin/magento cache:clear command.

Comment: please share your xml file path.

Comment: If you have run above commands than your file is not being executed. Please check your theme or module have the same file.
Like: app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/default_head_blocks.xml
Or
app/design/frontend/Yourtheme/Yourtheme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

Answer (score 0):

**If you use custom theme means follow the below steps**

```
1. Open the 'theme' table and update the type=0 for the particular custom theme.

2. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

3. php bin/magento c:f
```

**Finally we got the solution.**

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: @Tora Is it working fine?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't matter either you are clearing cache from admin console or from command line. It will clear all the active cache. Cache:flush will remove both "Active" and "Inactive" cache. The only difference is, when you remove the cache from command line, you need to set the permission back.

Can you show me what are you trying to update in "default_head_blocks.xml" file and where is it located in your theme?

Comment: Thanks, I was able to find the code on another page. it seems it was my browser cache.

Comment: Good to know you found which worked for you. Cheers !!!!